# Force cursor to input box immediately after webpage is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, angularjs

I would like to force the cursor to go to an input field immediately after the webpage is loaded. I am using AngularJS and the HTML code for the input field is as follows;

```
  <form novalidate="" class="simple-form">Identity number 
  <input type="text" ng-model="input_number" />
  <br />
  <button ng-click="submit()">SUBMIT</button></form>
```

How can this be done the AngularJS way? If not, using normal javascript or jquery are also welcomed.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use simply autofocus html5 attribute.But it is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks. This is the simplest solution of all.

Answer (score 2):

To complete @Felix answer, jQuery function should be wrapped inside a directive

```
yourapp.directive('autoFocus', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
      $element.focus();
    }
  };
});
```

And you can use the directive like this `<input type="text" auto-focus>`

Also some good reading: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)** with jQuery:

```
$('form input[type=text]:eq(0)').focus();
```