# can't getting textarea value using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
<tr class="labels">
    <td nowrap="nowrap">Address</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><label for="tbAddress"></label>
        <textarea name="tbAddress" id="tbAddress" cols="39" rows="5" ng-model="$parent.tbAddress"></textarea>

    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit Record" class="btns" />
        <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Cancel" class="btns" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not be able to get `textarea` value using AngularJS. All the `input` text fields are getting through the controller except the `textarea`. What am I doing wrong ?

```
alert($scope.tbAddress);
var thisData = {
    'name': $scope.tbFN,
    'company': $scope.tbCompany,
    'designation': $scope.tbDesignation,
    'email': $scope.tbEmail,
    'phone': $scope.tbPhone,
    'mobile': $scope.tbMobile,
    'address': $scope.tbAddress
};
```

It's alert undefined...

Comment: Have you tried `alert($scope.$parent.tbAddress);` ? What do you get ?

Comment: What is the scope context of your template? Are you using it in an `ngInclude` (judging by the `$parent`, you're either using that or perhaps a directive with isolate scope). Make sure the `$scope` var is actually the same in your controller as `$parent` in your template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `alert($scope.tbAddress);` positioned right there, of course it'll end up as `undefined`. Nothing has been assigned to `$scope.tbaddress` at this point. (but maybe you have it defined earlier, but it's just not being shown in the code).

I actually didn't have a problem getting it to work. I wrapped the alert in a function that is bound to the submit button. I'm able to get the value. [See my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4waBpNApqyaQqvdcUBns?p=preview).

I also took the liberty of changing your `$scope` a bit. It's recommended that every `ngModel` has a `.` in it's name. So rather than `tbAddress` it should be `tb.address`. It has to do with how angular inheritance is handled.

Refer to:

- [Why don't the AngularJS docs use a dot in the model directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)
- [The Dot - egghead video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot)
- [Google results for 'angular use dots in models'](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular%20use%20dot%20in%20models&oq=angular%20use%20dot%20in%20models&aqs=chrome..69i57.6634j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8)