# textarea value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I know it is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294691/cant-getting-textarea-value-using-angularjs) In controller below  I don't know how to get textarea value. In jquery I would just do  $("#textarea1").val(); but can't do it here. Also if I create new model i.e.note for textarea I can refer to it as $scope.note bit still don't know what how to make assign textarea to  it.

```
var app = angular.module("angularApp", []).controller("myConfigGenCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.textarea1 ="";
    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.textarea1 = "";
    };
    $scope.save  = function(data, filename) {
        data = $scope.textarea1;
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
        filename = "textarea.txt";
        console.log($scope.textarea1);
        saveAs(blob, filename);
    };
});
```

Here is html

```
<body ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-controller="myConfigGenCtrl">
        <form name="myform">
            <input type="text" ng-model="message1"/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="message2"/>
        </form>

        <p>
            <textarea id="textarea1" cols="80" rows="10">
                This is {{message1}} in 1st line
                This is {{message2}} in lastst line
            </textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
            <button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Assign an `ng-model` to it:

```
<p><textarea id="textarea1" cols="80" rows="10" ng-model="myTextArea">
  This is {{message1}} in 1st line
  This is {{message2}} in lastst line
</textarea></p>
```

Then you can get it from the controller with `$scope.myTextArea`

You could use also `$watch` to get data from other scope values and put into textarea:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/pdwqkm51/)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.$watch("message1", function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.myTextArea = "This is "+newVal+" in 1st line";
        }
    });

    $scope.save = function () {
        console.log($scope.myTextArea);
    };
}]);
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also use `ng-change` in your input text to change the `myTextArea` scope value:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/10f7r0gb/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="message1" ng-change="myTextArea = message1 + message2" />
<input type="text" ng-model="message2" ng-change="myTextArea = message1 + message2" />
<p>
    <textarea id="textarea1" cols="80" rows="10" ng-model="myTextArea" ></textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: I tried it before but it cleans my textarea  I can't type {{message1}} and {{message1}}  into it any more . Also console.log($scope.myTextArea); shows undefined

Comment: Define ```$scope.myTextArea``` in your controller.
Set the value from your controller: ```$scope.myTextArea = 'This is ' + $scope.message1 + ' in 1st line\nThis is ' + $scope. message2 + ' in lastst line';```

Comment: I want to change it in the view, not controller. But if I do this then I get  This is undefined in 1st lineThis is undefined in lastst line 111 222 after adding console.log($scope.myTextArea); console.log($scope.message1,$scope.message2)

Comment: I would like to editing textarea in controller, I need to edit it in View

Comment: There is something in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284442/cannot-get-textarea-value-in-angularjs talking about $parent

Comment: Appreciate but there is going to be a lot of text in that textarea and only few  models. So myTextArea is not only message1+message2. I can do it in jquery and it works using  data = $("#textarea1").val(); prefer  not to use jquery. Let me test your code , but I think it removes text around message1 and messag2

Comment: Just use a function in `ng-change` to return always the same text/variables

Comment: I tried but it gives me 111222 as myTextArea if message1 is 111 and message2 is 222. But my actual text is :  This is 111 in 1st line
      This is 222 in last line. ;(

Comment: I wrote only a test, just change `message1 + message2` with what you want: `'This is 1: ' + message1 + ' This is 2: ' + message2`

Comment: well, but this has to be done in controller which I want to avoid..I think I will stay with $("#textarea1").val();