# Strange scope when trying to clear input text via AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm having trouble with what I though would be a rather pedestrian use case. Given the following form

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="customerInput" size="80" class="form-control" placeholder="Type the company name here"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addCustomer(customerInput)">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I simply want to clear the input field after adding the customer.

```
  $scope.addCustomer = function(customer) {
    $scope.customers.push({name: customer});
    $scope.customerInput = '';
  }
```

It doesn't work, so I inspected the $scope. The `customerInput` value I'm looking for lives in the `$scope.$$childHead`. This works.

```
  $scope.addCustomer = function(customer) {
    $scope.customers.push({name: customer});
    $scope.$$childHead.customerInput = '';
  }
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model

Comment: With more testing, it only works when I turn off caching in devtools. Nevertheless, the value that I type in the form seems to be in the wrong `$scope`.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/49KLd/

Comment: @Blackhole is correct. It's something with another scope being injected because of the way I'm dynamically routing a submenu. I want to use one controller for two admin pages and that is creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular `$scope`s often do things that you don't expect because of the inheritance chain. For this reason, it's useful to define a Plain Old JavaScript var and reference that within the scope:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(function ($scope) {
    var model = {
        customerInput: ''
    };

    $scope.model = model;
});
```

And then in your template: `<input ng-model="model.customerInput" />`. Now you can operate on the `model` var in functions of that `$scope`, and be confident that only your chosen `$scope` is operating on that model. Of course, as you get more familiar with `$scope` inheritance patterns, you'll often *want* the implicit sharing between Controllers. And of course, in such a case, you could also store the data on a service.