# Toggling checkbox in AngularJS isn't reflected in the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a checkbox:

```
<input ng-model="defaultAssigneeCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
<p>{{defaultAssigneeCheckbox}}</p>

<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

Paragraph below it shows and updates its state properly between `false` and `true`.
Clicking button runs controller function:

```
$scope.updateProject = function () {
    var project = $scope.project;
    console.log(typeof $scope.defaultAssigneeCheckbox)
    console.log($scope.defaultAssigneeCheckbox)
    if (!$scope.defaultAssigneeCheckbox) {
        delete project.defaultAssignee;
    }
};
```

When I click button it shows the checkbox as true regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of console.log(typeof $scope.defaultAssigneeCheckbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** respect the ["dot rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model).

```
<input ng-model="data.defaultAssigneeCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: I have moved defaultAssigneeCheckbox to project object that I have already and it seemed to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem yesterday, try using ng-true-value & ng-false-value

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.value" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
```

In your case use true & false

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of console.log(typeof $scope.defaultAssigneeCheckbox)?  I have a feeling it's 'string' in which case $scope.defaultAssigneeCheckbox is always true.  therefore try this:

```
if ($scope.defaultAssigneeCheckbox != true) {
    delete project.defaultAssignee;
}
```

if that works figure out if you are ok with that or if you need to force a boolean.  In which case @Mario Campa's solution looks good. Personally, I'd prefer a boolean because experience dictates that it will be more useful in these cases.