# elasticui - Triggering sort with ng-click only firing on first click

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I'm trying to make the sort functionality work by creating two buttons: relevance and date.

I've set it up the following way:

```
<div ng-init="sort=false">
<a ng-click="sort=true">Date</a>
<a ng-click="sort=false">Relevance</a>
```

then on the container with the results:

```
<div eui-sort="ejs.Sort('post_date').order('desc')" eui-enabled="sort" >
```

The value set with `ng-init` properly affects the initial sort order and when I click `date` the list sorts as intended, but when I click `relevance` the list does not re-sort back as if `eui-enabled` was set to `false`.

I'm guessing underformed knowledge of Angular is causing me to oversimplify this. Any advice?

Comment: You talk of clicking `relevance`, you have not posted `relevance` markup or JS. Add a plnkr/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're running into the [AngularJS dot-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model), i.e.: the sort. A way to circumvent this is modifying sorting.sort within the eui-sort scope:

```
<div eui-sort="ejs.Sort('post_date').order('desc')" eui-enabled="true">
<a ng-click="sorting.enabled=true">Date</a>
<a ng-click="sorting.enabled=false">Relevance</a>
</div>
```

In this example, eui-enabled is only used for initialization since the value (true) doesn't change. Note that to reference the "sorting: object you must be inside the scope of the eui-sort (i.e.: inside the div)

Comment: did you mean to include `eui-enabled="sorting.enabled"`? Otherwise, I don't follow how the ng-clicks would have any affect on the eui-sort. Also, when I included the sort buttons inside the scope, I experienced the same problem: The sort took place only on the inital click of whatever was set to `ng-click="sorting.enabled=true"`

Comment: No, eui-enabled is actually a shorthand for setting sorting.enabled. Check out [the docs on euiSort and euiEnabled](https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI/blob/master/docs/components.md).

However, I see now that in the framework the sort is actually not removed when set to false - I hope to provide a fix for this tomorrow (so my initial diagnosis might have been wrong - my bad). If you provide a JSFiddle I'll make sure to test it against that.

Comment: Update: fixed in v0.0.3