# AngularJS : input ng-model not working when in a ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have the following code :

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div ng-if="myVar">
        <input ng-model="query">
     </div>
</div>
```

where `myVar` is `true`

- When the `<input>` is within the `ng-if` the `query` variable isn't created in the `$scope`.
- When it's outside the div (but still within the `ng-controller`) it works well.

Any idea why ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ngIf` creates new scope. Either [use a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model) in the model, or the *ControllerAs* syntax.