# why the functionality not working when the model name is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I make a demo which is working fine .I will explain the demo I have one text field and button .Whatever user type on text field then after  click button it show the text in pop up screen .when user write any thing on pop up screen and submit button press it display on screen

My Question that I take one model this **ng-model="modaldata.passedValue"**
but when I take **ng-model="passedValue"** my functionality stop why ?
I change every where is js also to **passedValue** instead of **modaldata.passedValue**
Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/PhXuubnDaYklqyoEdRtt?p=preview

here is code

```
  $scope.modalClick = function() {
      //alert($scope.modaldata.passedValue);
      textValue = $scope.modaldata.passedValue;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('modalSubmit', {
        modalText: $scope.modaldata.passedValue // send whatever you want
      });
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs
check this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This link might be of help:

```
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all occurrences of $scope.modaldata.passedValue to $scope.passedValue in the controller as well.

Comment: i already changed ...but functionlity break please check plunker..and edit the plunker