# AngularJS: reset function resets the table but not clears input field and select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, input

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label ng-hide="tab==1">Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=30" class="form-control review-input" min="0" step="10" ng-model="revNum" /></label>
    <label>Min Price &#163;: <input type="number" ng-init="minNum=0" class="form-control price-input" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="minNum" /></label>
    <label>Max Price &#163;: <input type="number" ng-init="maxNum=0" class="form-control price-input" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="maxNum" /></label>
    <label><select ng-model="currentCarType"  style="display:block;" ng-options="key for key in carTypeObj">
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
    </select></label>
    <label><button class="btn btn-primary " style="display:block;" ng-click="updateNumArray(revNum, minNum, maxNum); updateType(currentCarType)">Filter</button></label>
    <label><button class="btn btn-primary " style="display:block;" ng-click="resetNumArray(); resetType()">reset</button></label>
</form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
carApp.controller("TableBodyCtrl", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.revNum = 30;
    $scope.minNum = 0;
    $scope.maxNum = 0;
    $scope.currentCarType = null;

    $scope.resetType = function(){
        $scope.currentCarType = null;
    }

    $scope.resetNumArray = function(){
        $scope.revNum = 30;
        $scope.minNum = 0;
        $scope.maxNum = 0;
    }
```

When I click `reset` button my table updates and so `currentCarType`  is `null`, `revNum` is `30`, `minNum` is `0` and `maxNum` is `0`. But my `input` fields as well as my `select` are not update. How can I fix that?

Comment: hi, can you try this $scope.currentCarType = ''; instead of null within resetType function

Comment: the problem really was because of the dot issue in angular models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you probably are falling for the problem discussed here:
[Why don't the AngularJS docs use a dot in the model directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)

The input's model is initialized on a parent scope, but as soon as you edit in there the value is stored in a child scope and subsequently also read from there.