# AngularJS undefined scope variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, slim-lang

My problem is that every time select tag is change the value $scope.variationValue inside ProductContooller.js.coffee is undefine. Any idea why its undefine?

*ProductContoller.js.coffee*

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers')
controllers.controller("ProductController", [ '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location','Restangular'
  ($scope,$routeParams,$location,Restangular)->

    $scope.update_variation = ()->
      console.log $scope.variationValue <---- undefined why?

    Restangular.one('products', $routeParams.id).get().then (c) ->
      $scope.price = c.cheapest_variant.price
      $scope.product = c
      return
])
```

*product.html.slim*

```
.form-group
  label for="sel1"  Variations:
  select ng-options="variant as variant.opt1_value for variant in product.variants" ng-model="variationValue" ng-change="update_variation()"
  | Value {{variationValue.price}}
```

Comment: most likely because you are using a primitive for `ng-model` which is really bad practice. Always have a `dot` in `ng-model` reflecting that you are thus binding to an object in order for inheritance to work

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean dot in ng-model?

Comment: one of the more important overall concepts to understand when working with angular . Follow as many of the links as you can in this post [angularjs-dot-in-ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)

Comment: @charlietfl still does not work

Comment: You probably have a child scope or several between controller and scope of the element. If you define that object in controller then inheritance will work. Don't have to add properties since `ng-model` will do that for you if they aren't already defined. If you already did that create demo that replicates problem