# ng-include controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having a problem in AngularJs when using ng-include to include an html template that has its own controller.

The problem in short is that I am able access scope variables defined in the controller of the included template in the template itself but can't do the opposite (accessing a model defined in the template inside its controller).

This is my index.html page at which I include test.html template:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TestController" ng-include="'test.html'"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the test.html template:

```
<div>
{{foo}}
<br />
<input type="text" ng-model="username" />{{username}}
<br />
<button ng-click="go()">Click here</button>
</div>
```

And finally this is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'Hello World';
  $scope.go = function() {
    console.log('Username = ' + $scope.username);
  }
});
```

With no problem I can do the following:

- Accessing foo that is defined in the controller in the template
- Accessing username that is defined in the template in the template
  itself

But I can't do the following

- Accessing username that is defined in the template in the controller
  (the output is undefined in the go() function)

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNjsNZOV0SLRkINsxZGM).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: dot in ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)

Comment: I've read this one already and I think my case is different. I did try to use  **info.username** as a name for the model instead but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what i suggest you to do is alias your controller and inser the model in its scope.

**Alias your controller:**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as testCtrl" ng-include="'test.html'"></div>
```

Actually this code is allowing you to use testCtrl to prefix your variables and isert them in your scope.

**Inser the model in the controller scope:**
So now you can insert your model in the scope.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testCtrl.username" />{{testCtrl.username}}
```

So now in your controller you can access to that variable like that:

```
$scope.testCtrl.username
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `ng-include` directive creates new scope always when it is included,

instead of declaring your controller in

`<div ng-controller="TestController" ng-include="'test.html'"></div>`

declare it in `test.html` itself,

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
 {{foo}} <br />
 <input type="text" ng-model="username"/>    {{username}}     <br />
 <button ng-click="go()">Click here</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the problem with creating a new scope? I mean why do I face the above problem (accessing the scope in the view but not vice versa)

Comment: Its because `ng-include` creates a new child scope, which is inherited from TestController scope or its parent scope and this child scope is not accessible to parent scope.

Comment: Ah I see! First `ng-controller` runs ([priority 500](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)), creating a new scope, *then* `ng-include` runs ([priority 400](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)), creating yet another child scope. And the controller only has access to the parent scope. Brilliant!