# AngularJS: Model not updating in controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($interval, $scope) {
    $scope.foo = 2;
    $interval(function() {
        console.log($scope.foo);
    }, 1000);
});
```

And the following code in my view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" />
```

When I load the page, the input is correctly populated with the value "2".  However, if I change the value in the input, the console continues to log "2" (without quotes).

I've used an `$interval` just to illustrate - with `$watch()` the callback only fires once and then never again.  If I use `ng-change=""` on the input, then `$scope.foo` in the callback is always equal to 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this fragment of code, you've wrote. Check example: http://plnkr.co/edit/vaK63tDaBhnVLk4rC11z?p=preview. How do you instantiating your controllers and app?

Comment: @Andrey I use $routeProvider to create a route to MyCtrl:

    $routeProvider
        .when('/my', {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/my.html',
            controller: 'MyCtrl'
        })

And app is instantiated as var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

Comment: Can you provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This is a small part of a larger ng app, but judging by the fact that your plunker worked, I think there's something else somewhere in app which is interfering.

Comment: Read about angular dot rule.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use ng-model, you have to have a dot in [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model) .

Bind model by creating a object like this

**controller**

```
$scope.form={
   foo:0
};
```

**view**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.foo" />
```

Comment: That works great.  Are you able to explain to me what made you suggest this?

Comment: sometimes angular push scope  in upper layer in your controller scope. if you bind direct varable into model then this variable can be add into  newly added scope by which is current scope. but if you use bind by object property then whatever scope may push by angular the relation between object doesn't break

Comment: @NeilGarb A decent blog post from a while back covers [5 AngularJS Anti-Patterns and Pitfalls](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/). The first on the list is forgetting the dot.

Comment: You saved my time brother.

Comment: THANKS! I'm maintaining an old angular application. I introduced a new property in the scope and I've been struggling for *weeks* to understand why my property did not update. I created an object and put the property as a child on that object; now all works!