# angular js - scope variable dont change on 2 way data binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new with angular js.

my controller is :
    var myapp= angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

```
// configure our routes
myapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/person.html',
            controller  : 'personController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/add', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/addGroup.html',
            controller  : 'groupController'
        });
});
myapp.controller('groupController', function($scope) {
        $scope.user = 'alex';
        $scope.print = function() 
        {
            alert($scope.user);
        };
    });
```

my view is :

```
<div ng-controller="groupController">
  Your name: <input type="text" ng-model="user">
    <button ng-click='print()'>Print</button>
  {{user}}
</div>
```

when I change the input value to "mila" for example its reflect in the view,
but when I click the print button I am still getting alert with "alex" name.

how can I make the scope.user to change also ?
I cant understand what is missing here for 2 way data binding.
thanks !

Comment: It is working for me. Have a look at - http://plnkr.co/edit/7itpNdFR6LQRg2uHJFrr?p=preview

Comment: it is working fine me also - https://jsfiddle.net/yhv9bjrx/1/

Comment: @mashiah  - Sounds like you didn't understand 2 way data binding clearly

Comment: maybe Its not working for me because I am using routing also ? I edit my question with my full model. thanks

Comment: You have double declaration of controller. Once via `ng-controller="groupController"` and then again via `$routeProvider`  Then most likely the controller is initialized twice

Comment: I delete the "ng-controller="groupController" from the div, and its still not working for me. i think that something in thr routing is ruining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things,

- Check if you have `<div ng-view=""></div>` in you `index.html` or which ever your source page is. This is where your different views, i.e., the views (`person.html` , `addGroup.html`) stated under routing would get injected.
- Remove the declaration of `ng-controller="groupController"` from `addGroup.html`
- Double check if the URLs you have provided under routing are correct.
- Which version of angular are you using? Check if the version that you are using requires `angular-route.js`. If so please include this js.

Check if you score all positives on above mentioned bullets!

Comment: thanks its works now. one more question - why do I need to remove the  ng-controller="groupController" from the addGroup.html ?

Comment: that's because you have already assigned the controller for `addGroup.html` to be `groupController` while declaring the routes here as, `$routeProvider..when('/add', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/addGroup.html',
            controller  : 'groupController'
        });` .You dont need to assign the controller again in your html, so you shouldn't do a `ng-controller="groupController"`. Also, please accept the answer by checking the "tick" mark near the answer if you think it solved your issue :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This works. So i think there is something wrong with the routing or there is something that breaks the binding.

Here is your own example without the routning:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {

  $scope.user = 'alex';
  $scope.print = function() {
    alert($scope.user);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  Your name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="user">
  <button ng-click='print()'>Print</button>
  {{user}}
</div>
```

There are two possible solutions and the rigth one depends on what is causing the problem.

Solution no 1 - pass the user to the print function:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {

  $scope.user = 'alex';
  $scope.print = function(user) {
    alert(user);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  Your name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="user">
  <button ng-click='print(user)'>Print</button>
  {{user}}
</div>
```

Solution no 2 - use a comlpex object:
(also check [this](https://thinkster.io/egghead/the-dot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model) out.)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {

  $scope.user = {
    name: 'alex'
  };
  $scope.print = function() {
    alert($scope.user.name);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  Your name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
  <button ng-click='print()'>Print</button>
  {{user.name}}
</div>
```