# $watch or ng-model binding issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I basically have a very complicated set of tabs with various input controls but lets not worry about this for now. For now let consider simple input wtching issue I am baffled by.

For example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Associate some tags please" data-ng-model="tag" data-ng-maxlength="250">
```

I am try to detect if user has typed something into my input:

```
$scope.$watch('tag', function () {
//$scope.$watchCollection('tag', function () {
    console.log('tag changed');
});
```

But I seem to get zero response. However, when I perform my save operation I always seem to get the value user typed in.

Is a case of `ng-model` not binding correctly or is it that I am not `$watch`ing it correctly?

Also after I've performed my save operation I try to clear what user typed in for the tag with:

```
$scope.tag = '';
```

But that doesn't seem to work for some reason as though `$scope.tag` doesn't exist.

PS: When I say save operation I am actually performing a `array.push()` into an object which later gets saved by a service.

For example:

```
$scope.checkSaveTag = function (tag) {
    ...
    // checked for duplicate tag beforehand
    $scope.myForm.Tags.push(tagObj); // complicated form object
    $scope.tag = ''; // tag input control
    ...
};
```

Comment: it seems `tag` is in a different scope than your `watch` and `checkSaveTag` ,is it?

Comment: @DivyaMV so it would seem. But I don't quite understand why this would be the case. Everything is defined within the same controller.

Comment: is the `input` inside any ng-repeat or ng-if?

Comment: instead of tag try using`ng-model=myObj.tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance that the tag is an object or an array? If that is the case, you'll need to do a deep $watch, e.g:

```
$scope.$watch('tag', function () {
    console.log('tag changed');
}, true);
```

Comment: Why did you die , Jon Snow ?? :'(

Comment: @JonShow I tried that too but nothing changed. It would seem that I cannot read my model from inside my controller ``$scope.tag``. Very strange.

Comment: The tag might be getting declared on a child scope instead. Try declaring something like `$scope.obj = {}` and set the ng-model to `obj.tag` and then watch the `obj.tag` instead.

Comment: You're welcome, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model to see why not having a dot in your ng-model can be a pitfall.

Comment: I see, I will certainly dig a bit more into this when I have a bit of spare time. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**Controller**

```
$scope.form={
 tag:''
}

$scope.$watch("form.tag",function(newVal,oldVal){
  console.log(newVal);
})
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Associate some tags please" data-ng-model="form.tag" data-ng-maxlength="250">
```

Comment: Sorry buddy but @JonShow got there a bit ahead of you. But both of you are absolutely correct. By encapsulating number of free form inputs that I had problem with into scoped object I am able to ``$watch`` them.