# Doesn't work two ways of filtering (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter, filtering

I'm trying to make two ways of filtering (via clicking on letters or via typing in input field).

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul search-list=".letter" model="search">
        <li class="letter" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet.letter">{{ letter }}</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="CountriesController">

        <input id="q" type="text" ng-model="search " />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="country in countries.country | filter:search:startsWith">{{ country }}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
```

and js:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
var controllers = {};
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");



app.directive('searchList', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            searchModel: '=model'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', attrs.searchList, function() {
                scope.searchModel = $(this).text();
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});

controllers.MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.setTerm = function(letter) {
        $scope.search = letter;
    };
    $scope.alphabet = {
      letter: alphabet
    }
};
controllers.CountriesController = function($scope){

  $scope.countries = {
    country:['Ukraine','Urugvai','Russia','Romania','Rome','Argentina','Britain']
  }
  $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
};



app.controller(controllers);
```

On first look everything is working fine, but it is so only on first look...

When at first I click on any letter - filter works good.
When then I'm typing in input field - filter works good.
But after I typed in input field or delete text from there via 'backspace' button - filter by clicking on letters stops working...

Why it works like this and how I can fix this issue?
Here is my [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrS2zNCXJwAznMiX50p2?p=preview)

Thanx in advance!

Comment: The problem is scope inheritance. The moment you actually type into the input field, the scope of `CountriesController` will have it's own value for `search` and no longer inherit it from `MainController`. This could be resolved if you follow the [dot-rule](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17606936/697154).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem fount for using two controler's. If you remove `CountriesController` , then everything working good.

The `Search` values was confused with which controller using that scope object.**I think you don't need implement two controller for this scenario**

See the [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WvRhnRhNnseW2XhA6p09?p=preview) if you remove `CountriesController`.

Comment: Thank You for your explanation. But may be is better to add  '$parent.' to 'ng-model="search"', just in case if on ather page I'll need to use only CountriesController without filtering on click?

Answer (score 1):

change this part of html to this it works fine (ng-model="$parent.search ")

```html
   <div class="container" ng-controller="CountriesController">

        <input id="q" type="text" ng-model="$parent.search " />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="country in countries.country | filter:search:startsWith">{{ country }}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Your snippet code is running good? i think it's showing error :(

Comment: no , not showing any errors here is a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/xZPEb9Y6eI3jZq0ppOiv?p=preview

Comment: actually adding '$parent.' to ;ng-model="search"' works very good

Comment: @TahaAmineZeghbib I'm still choosing between yours answer and answer from Ramesh Rajendran