# Replacing existing objects in array using foreach loops javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am working on array with javascript. I am able to add the array by using push. However, I am not sure how to edit an items. As you can see in this link below
, I have the push method for my add item, which is working fine. But what should I do with my edit button if I want to change replacing the old item with the new one? Do I need to use foreach to do it?  Help will be appreciated `jsfiddle.net/hin123/tcVhN/127/`

I am stuck with this part
    $scope.saveDetail = function (data) {
      //angular.foreach
        }

Comment: Need to post your code. There's a reason you couldn't use a fiddle link without code...questions need to be self contained for several reasons....number one is for people to be able see it without having to leave the site.....then add the fiddle link

Comment: You need to find the index of object you want to edit ..

Comment: Hi sorry, I have posted my link, @RayonDabre, can you help me through with the link that I just updated?

Comment: Hi Madness, It is in the controller, under the onItemDelete

Comment: Major issue in your `ng-model` binding... always have a dot in ng-model ....must read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model. Your edit form is broken due to this issue. A single object in the scope to fix this issue also makes all the form data simpler to code in controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.splice() to insert items, eg.

```
    $scope.tempData.splice($scope.tempData.indexOf(oldData), 1, newData);
```

Comment: hi mofojed, where should I defined the newData?