# Update parent scope value from child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have code like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app1.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body ng-app ='directivesModule'>
    <div class='main' ng-controller="customersController">
        <input type='text' ng-model='firsttext'>
        <button name='hello1' ng-click="showsecond = !showsecond;thirdtext='pradeep'">show second</button>
        <div class='second' ng-show='showsecond'>
            <input type='text'  ng-model='secondtext'>
            <button name='hello2' ng-click="showthird = !showthird">show third</button>
            {{firsttext}}
        </div>
         <div class='third' ng-if='showthird'>
            <input type='text'  ng-model='thirdtext'>
            <button name='hello' ng-click="changeparent()">hello</button>
            {{secondtext}}
            {{firsttext}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And JS looks like

```
var app = angular.module('directivesModule', []);

    app.controller('customersController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.changeparent = function()
        {
            $scope.firsttext = $scope.thirdtext;
            console.log($scope.thirdtext);
        };

    }]);
```

May be code is very clear what i am trying to do. So what child value is there i am trying to update the same to first text box. But not possible.I know i can do it either by using emit or passing paramaters to function. BUt is there any other best method to take care of it. Ng-show i dono wanna use as element will be present in DOM.

Comment: ALWAYS use objects in `ng-model`. You already have a broken binding due to the child scope created by `ng-if` and there is no inheritance for primitives like there is for objects

Comment: ^100% correct. To explain why you need to use an Object (a "dot" in the binding attribute), here's another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/624590

Comment: Got how to fix this. DOT is the solution for same :)