# AngularJS $scope form attribute is undefined after ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I'm starting with Angular and I'm still very confused with syntax and the many different ways I can code to get the same result.

My latest problem is that when I submit a form, I can't get its values by doing `$scope.attribute_name`

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-include src="'menu.html'"></div>
        <div id="container" ng-controller="MainController">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**login.html (included by Route)**

```
<form name="form" name='' action="" ng-submit='login($event)'>
    <input type="text" name='username' ng-model='username' required />
    <input type="text" name='password' ng-model='password' required />
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
 app.controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.login = function ($event){
            alert($scope.username)
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
}]);
```

It always alert "undefined"
I can get the values by doing the following

```
$event.target.username
```

Just like on Meteor.

Any ideas?

**@edit1**

I added user as the model's object

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" name='teste' action="" ng-submit='login($event)'>
    <input type="text" name='username' ng-model='user.username' required />
    <input type="text" name='password' ng-model='user.password' required />
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.login = function ($event){
        alert($scope.user.username)
}
}]);
```

I still get `undefined` though

Comment: always...always..always use an object in ng-model...it's a golden rule

Comment: What he means by that comment is to make sure that you're binding to an object  (eg: `<input type="email" ng-model="user.email">`) and not a primitive value like a string (eg don't do this:  `<input type="email" ng-model="email">` ). The problem is that some directives (`ng-if`, `ng-include`, etc) create child scopes using prototypical inheritance. This breaks the binding when the model is a primitive value (as opposed to an object). It's probably the most common problem people run into w/Angular.

Comment: Some light reading for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17606936/398606 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14049480/398606

Comment: how can I access username at controller? I still get undefined

Comment: If you bound the input to the model with `ng-model="user.username"` then you would access this in the controller using `$scope.user.username`

Comment: You will also need to declare the `user` object on the scope, so that any child scopes have an object to inherit... Add `$scope.user = { };` to the first line of the controller so that object exists before the child scopes are created.

Comment: it works now, Sunil. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form" name='teste' action="" ng-submit='login()'>
    <input type="text" name='username' ng-model='user.username' required />
    <input type="text" name='password' ng-model='user.password' required />
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

define your $scope inside the controller as below. Because attributes are registered to the $scope of the controller when the controller initializes.

```
app.controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.user={}; //DEFINE $scope variable if dot is given to variable.
    $scope.login = function (){
        alert($scope.user.username)
}
}]);
```

Thanks