# Why would ng-bind work, where {{}} is not

Tags: angularjs, django

If I have in my `controller` something like:

```
...
 $scope.arr = ["orange", "apple", "pear"];
...
```

Why would the following work:

```
...
<li data-ng-repeat="item in arr">
  <span data-ng-bind="item"></span>
</li>
...
```

Output (as expected):

- orange
- apple
- pear

And this *not* work:

```
...
<li data-ng-repeat="item in arr">
  <span>{{item}}</span>
</li>
...
```

Output:

- 
- 
- 

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), they should both work the same, no?

**EDIT**:

Looks like it [does work](http://plnkr.co/edit/J9EW5dUvF8zuAeMAVWX8?p=preview). Any common issues that might cause this type of behavior?

**EDIT 2**:

Figured it out (solution below). The key factor was that I'm suing [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).

Comment: It should work... [**plnkr demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/J9EW5dUvF8zuAeMAVWX8?p=preview). It must be something else isn't shown that is going on.

Comment: Thank you, @NewDev! I didn't even think to sanity check in a sandbox. Once I find the culprit, I'll update this question and/or answer it.

Comment: best practice is to always bind to a property of an object, or put another way [Always use dots](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17606936/4320665)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using another web framework (i.e. Django) that will be parsing your Angular templates, make sure you instruct the parser to leave the Angular expressions as is.

In Django you would just wrap the code in [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) tags:

```
...
{% verbatim %}

  {{angularExpressions}}

{% endverbatim %}
...
```