# ng-include doesn't render partial view everytime using $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

inside view I'm conditionally rendering html using ng-include and ng-if

```
 <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-if="myProperty == 1">
            <div ng-include="'view1.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="myProperty == 2">
            <div ng-include="'view2.html'"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

and inside controller I have $scope.myProperty which receive value inside controller using $scope injection from other js object. On this controller I have also callback function which updates $scope.myProperty every x seconds.

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
   ...
        $scope.myProperty = 0; //init value
        function callback() {
            $scope.$apply(); // force update view
            // correctly write myProperty value on every data change
            console.log($scope.myProperty); 
        }
    var otherJsObject= new myObject($scope, callback);
    otherJsObject.work();
   ...
}
```

callback function correctly change `myProperty` value but it doesn't update inside view every time.

update:
$scope.bindUIProp = { a: $scope.myProperty};

```
    function callback() {
        $scope.$apply(); 
        $scope.bindUIProp.a = $scope.myProperty;            
        console.log('Callback  ' + $scope.myProperty);
        console.log('drawstage  ' + $scope.bindUIProp.a);

    }

    var otherJsObject= new myObject($scope, callback);
    otherJsObject.work();
```

and inside view I used object property

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
            <div ng-if="bindUIProp.a == 1">
                <div ng-include="'view1.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="bindUIProp.a == 2">
                <div ng-include="'view2.html'"></div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

this approach work every time when page is refreshed, parial view is not updated from view1 to view2 when scope.bindUIProp.a is changed to 2.

Comment: I suppose you should show us more of your code. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try to put the example in jsfiddle or codepen.io or plunker

Comment: It *may* be a scope issue, try using the dot notation, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model

Answer (score 1):

Both `ng-if` and `ng-include` create child scopes.

You are having problems due to using a primitive in your main scope. Primitives don't have inheritance so the binding is getting broken in the nested child scopes.

change it to an object:

```
$scope.myProperty = { someProp: 0};
```

Personally I rarely use `ng-include` because of the child scope it creates. I prefer having my own directive if all I want is to include a template.

Comment: thanks I'll try this. Is there an alternative then for ng-include?

Comment: Use angular directives

Comment: @JayJayJay agree...but keep in mind `ng-include` is a directive also, just a built in one

Comment: Oh thanks :). Should read up more so my comments can be more precise

Comment: @user1765862 it is best practice to always use objects in your scope models anyway

Comment: Even if you were to use custom directives, as charlie mentions, it is best practise to use objects to enclose a property you bind to especially you are binding to the property and going to be making changes to the property

Comment: I updated question. It works only when page is refreshed until first view change. Any ideas?

Comment: make a demo . I'm not clear on what you are trying to do with `function cb()` or `new myObject` or new myObject

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing to property at root level. Write one level below.

Instead of $scope.myProperty,

use $scope.mp.myProperty