# Why value assignment using ngClick inside ngRepeat wont work

Tags: angularjs

```
<ul>
    <li  ng-repeat="val in [1,2,3]">
    <button ng-click="dummy = '{{val}}'">{{val}}</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>Value : {{dummy}}</div>
```

I am trying to assign a value when the button is clicked but its not working.

Comment: <button ng-click="dummy = val ">{{val}}</button>

Answer (score 4):

`ng-repeat` creates its own scope. Since the button is in the `ng-repeat`, it has an individual scope, and can't access the `dummy` value. To prevent this, your need to [use a dot in your ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/4506790).

Here is your code, corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/844k52bh/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sg39rypn/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.changeDummyVal=function(val){
        $scope.dummy=val;
    }
});
```

You can make function for it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
ng-click="dummy = val "
```

i.e

```
<ul>
<li  ng-repeat="val in [1,2,3]">
<button ng-click="dummy = val ">{{val}}</button>
</li>
</ul>
<div>Value : {{dummy}}</div>
```