# $scope.currentPage not updating - Angular Ui Pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui

I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQXwYY), and using the function **`'$scope.pageChanged'`** to see when a page is changed.

```
$scope.pageChanged = function() {
 $log.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
};
```

But when I click on page links (changing a page), the variable **`'$scope.currentPage'`** doesn't changes. Why?

I think is something about the **`filter`**, but not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
```

to

```
$scope.pagination = {
    currentPage:  1
};
```

And as a consequence, it should be:

```
... pagination: pagination.currentPage
... ng-model="pagination.currentPage"
... $log.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.pagination.currentPage);
```

You can group also other variables like `maxSize` in `pagination`. Avoid to bind primitives directly to the `$scope`.

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaXMQy)**

Comment: Thats awsome ! Why I have to make an object `$scope.pagination{}`?

Comment: Basically this is because the variable is inherited in the pagination directive scope and changed from here. If you want more details about this problem you can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the binding with primitive issue.  But how come the demo works?
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination