# ng-model is undefined wih ng-if but working with ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I have very basic functionality which is like get text value on click function. I have a text box inside ng-if. But when I am trying to get the value it says '`undeifned`' I red about it and came to know that ng-if create its own scope. So if it is true then why click function is working which is defined in controller.
Both are defined in controller.
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/L9q8y27vmKmrY0TkdzW9?p=preview)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.comment="";
  $scope.showBox = function (){
    $scope.showTextBox = true;
  }
  $scope.getComment = function (){
    alert($scope.comment);
    $scope.showTextBox = false;
  }

});
```

Comment: Your `ng-model` should always have a dot in it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/373655 . You may want to look into using the "controller as" syntax as it will take care of this for you

Comment: You can use ng-show="CONDITION" instead of ng-if. It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-if creates a new child scope. ng-show does not.
I'm guessing the $scope.comment is defined inside the ng-if.

If you don't want to use ng-show, sometime using an object instead of a simple variable will work. Ex:

```
$scope.comment= { c: "" };
alert($scope.comment.c);
<textarea ng-model="comment.c">
```

Updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DewF13GWVIS8bHQIIAbC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use dot(.) in your scopes to save yourself from inheritance issues in AngularJS.

Try to add an object and add properties over it, like - `$scope.data = {};` and then add `$scope.data.comment = {};`

Code -

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.data.comment="";
  $scope.showBox = function (){
    $scope.data.showTextBox = true;
  }
  $scope.getComment = function (){
    alert($scope.data.comment);
    $scope.data.showTextBox = false;
  }

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/33ENoFi6qHRPDJUjc6tc?p=preview