# ng-show not working on nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this JSON structure like this:

```
{
  "products": {
    "318": {
      "id": 318,
      "product_id": 32,
      "sold_by": 1,
      "sold_from_date": 1452075077,
      "sold_to_date": 1459937477,
      "product_price": "1,200",
      "renewed_for": 0,
      "renewed": {
        "319": {
          "id": 319,
          "product_id": 32,
          "sold_by": 1,
          "sold_from_date": 1452075077,
          "sold_to_date": 1459937477,
          "product_price": "1,200",
          "renewed_for": 318
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To print the data, I have to loop through two ng-repeat

the first is the outer loop to print the details of 318. Next is 319, which is parent of 318. Parent is decided through `renewed_for` index.

In the first block of ng-repeat, I have some options like edit and delete. On clicking these, a pop-up opens. 
In the second (inner) block of ng-repeat, options are same for edit and delete.

```
<div ng-repeat=data in products>
    <div class=edit ng-click="showEdit = true">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat=renew in data>
        <div class=edit ng-click="showEdit = true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" ng-show="showEdit">
        <div class="product_price">{{data.product_price}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The showEdit popup works only for outer loop, and not for the inner (renew) loop.

EDIT: Now, when I open the pop-up from the inner loop(renew), the value that I get in it is the value of outer loop (data). How to solve this??

Comment: Post your controller and how you open the popup. or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Is the inner loop running ...  I mean can u see the divs of inner loop ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-repeat creates a new scope.
you will have to do

```
$parent.showEdit = true
```

in the inner ng-repeat instead.

but the even better approach would be not to use "undotted" variables in the first place. look here:

[Why don't the AngularJS docs use a dot in the model directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)

here's a working example:

```
<div ng-repeat=data in products>
    <div class=edit ng-click="showEdit = true; content = data;">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat=renew in data>
        <div class=edit ng-click="$parent.showEdit = true; $parent.content = renew;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" ng-show="$parent.showEdit">
        <div class="product_price">{{content.product_price}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much better to use an object in the model instead of primitive and avoid using `$parent`. The nested `ng-repeat` would require `$parent.$parent` which gets ugly in a hurry with structural changes

Comment: yeah thats why i said the shouldn't use "undotted" variables and linked the other topic :)

Comment: i already answered your question. also your edited question. this has the exact same reason. ng-repeat creates a new scope which is why your code behaves like it behaves. you should read the link i posted and fix the code accordingly (use dotted variables like "myobject.showEdit" instead of "showEdit")

Comment: But in my modal I am using `data` to show items. And in my second loop, it is replaced by `renewed`. So, how will it take the `renewed` object into consideration?

Comment: Isn't the problem with ng-repeat?

Comment: your "showEdit" in your second loop is a different "showEdit" than in your outer loop. because ng-repeat creates a new scope as mentioned. you have to google for "ng-repeat" and "new scope" for deeper understanding. or read the article i posted. i don't understand what your question is to be honest. see my edited post for an example what i mean

Comment: The problem here is the data I want to show in popup has to be different. That is when I click on the outer loop's edit, it should show me data for `318` (the parent). And if I click on outer loop's edit, popup should show me the data for `319` (child - inner loop)

Comment: then you will have to use a different variable name for the inner loop showEdit, e.g. showEdit2
but still you will have to put it into an object or use $parent (not recommended)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100503/discussion-between-phantomphoenix-and-patrick-kelleter).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an object containing a boolean `showEdit` property instead of a boolean on your `$scope` inside your controller like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dataUI = {
        showEdit: true
    };
}

<div ng-repeat=data in products>
    <div class=edit ng-click="dataUI.showEdit = true">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat=renew in data>
        <div class=edit ng-click="dataUI.showEdit = true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" ng-show="dataUI.showEdit">
    //Code for edit modal
    </div>
</div>
```

Lots of posts explains why:
http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/