# Angular UI Bootstrap Pagination ng-model not updating

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use a UI Bootstrap Pagination directive in my project, but for some strange reason the ng-model used for updating the current page is not working. The pagination is showing up correctly with the correct number of tabs and everything, but when I click on a different number, the ng-model variable is not getting updated. For the life of me, I can't figure out why not.

The code I am using is taken from the examples on the UI Bootstrap homepage:

```
<uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"
  ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pagination>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.totalItems = 160;

$scope.pageChanged = function() {
  console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
};
```

Here are the different required sources I am including:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.0.3.js"></script>
```

The strangest thing is I have created a plnkr which replicates my code and it works! You can see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4DoKnRACbKjLnMH5vGB6

Can anybody think of any ideas that might be causing this not to work? I'm scratching my head here, and can't think of anything obvious I am doing wrong...

All help much apprecatiated!

Comment: Classic case of not using an object in `ng-model`. This is a golden rule in angular

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean Charlietfl? Tell us more...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model

Comment: @charlietfl It seems this was not working because it was inside a uib-tab. When I take it out of the uib-tab it works. So is this ng-model getting messed up by some scope confusion you think?

Comment: did you change it to object? Nested scopes are why you can't use primitives for `ng-model`

Comment: no - I just changed the position of the pagination within the html so it wouldn't get mixed up with the <uibtab> scope. When you say object, what is the syntax exactly?

Comment: did you look at link above I provided? Watch the video linked in first answer

Comment: Actually @charlietfl the angular-ui docs use $scope.currentPage  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/docs/demo.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I ran through the same problem and solved it by wrapping all Angular UI Bootstrap Pagination parameters into the object, like so:

### JS

```
$scope.pagination = {
    currentPage: 1,
    maxSize: 21,
    totalItems: data.count
};
```

### HTML

```
<uib-pagination
    total-items="pagination.totalItems" 
    ng-model="pagination.currentPage" 
    max-size="pagination.maxSize"
    boundary-link-numbers="true" 
    ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pagination>
```

Comment: Thanks .You save my time

Comment: Do you know precisely (or have a theory) why this happens sometimes with the binding?

Comment: Weird. After including those properties in an object, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue.  Found that the bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js was causing this issue.  Just replaced it with bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js to make it work.

Below is the library combination that works:

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>  
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
```