# AngularJS : Correct usage of ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I was reading Angular js docs when I came across the issues mentioned related to using `ng-model` with directives like `ng-include` , `ng-switch` , and `ng-view`.The  reason mentioned was `child scope` and `parent scope` but I was not able to understand it completely. 
Also it was mentioned that issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your `ng-model`. 
Here's the [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) 
Can anyone please explain it in less-technical language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs?rq=1 - best explanation of scopes in Angular.

Comment: Check out egghead video in first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model 3 minutes of enlightenment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include`, `ng-switch` and `ng-if` creates child scope.
It means that if you create

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id="innerDiv" ng-if="!something">
    <input ng-model="model">
  </div>
</div>`
```

the `model` will be created in scope created by the `#innerDiv` (because of using `ng-if`). It might be problematic if you want to use `model` value in the controller, because it won't be possible (Parent scope has no access to properties of child scope!).

The solution is to use `$parent.model` in `<input ng-model="model">`. Then the property will be changed in parent's scope and that is what you usually want to achieve.

However using `$parent` might look not good for someone, so better solution is to create a named model in the controller. The you can use it and follow the rule "always have a '.' in your ng-model." Child scope created by `ng-if` has access to parrent scope, so he can use already defined `$scope.model` and change `$scope.model.text` property.

Controller:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div id="innerDiv" ng-if="!something">
     <input ng-model="model.text">
   </div>
</div>`
```

(But remember that if you not define `$scope.model` in the controller, it would behave like in first example).

If you are not sure that you are in the same scopes, you can check it by displaying scope's `$id`. Simply add in html `{{$id}}` above `ng-if` (or `ng-include`, `ng-switch`) and inside.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   scope id: {{$id}}
   <div id="innerDiv" ng-if="!something">
     child scope id:{{$id}}
   </div>
   <div>scope id again {{$id}}</div>
</div>`
```

Some examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/La90btfh/3/