# Change index of AngularJS md-tabs have no effect at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-material

In my Angular app, I have a md-tabs whose md-selected directive is binded to a property in my controller. I'd like to change the current tab to the one whose index is set by a function called by ng-click somewhere else in my template.

I did it this way:

```
<div ng-controller="TrackingCtrl" layout-fill>
   <md-content ng-if="isSmart" layout-fill>
      <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" layout-fill>
         <md-tab>.........</md-tab>
         <md-tab>.........</md-tab>
         <md-tab>.........</md-tab>
         <md-tab>
            <md-tab-label>{{ 'tracking.positions.TITLE' | translate }}</md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
                <md-tab-content layout-fill flex>
                    <button ng-click="map.panTo(getPosition());displayMap();"></button>
            </md-tab-body>
         </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
 </md-content>
</div>
```

In my controller I have :

```
  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
  $scope.displayMap = function() {
      $scope.selectedIndex = 1;
  };
```

But it has no effect at all when I click my button which calls displayMap();

I've inspected the problem:

- When I set $scope.selectedIndex = 1; in my controller, the default tab is the one whose index is 1. **OK**
- When I set md-selected="1" in my template, the default tab is the one whose index is 1. **OK**
- When I set a breakpoint in my code, and when I click my button, displayMap() is called, and $scope.selectedIndex = 1; is executed. **OK**

It seems everything works fine... except the tab doesn't change.

I'm running Angular Material 1.0.2

I even used $apply to force update (no effect) :

```
  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
  $scope.displayMap = function () {
      $timeout(function () {
          if (!$scope.$$phase) {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                  $scope.selectedIndex = 1;
              });
          }
      });
  };
```

Comment: FYI - $timeout by itself will trigger $apply internally . Doesn't answer question ... just passing on info

Comment: Suggest check in angular-material github issue tracker also. Lots of tabs issues there

Comment: Yes I will check this out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem which was certainly caused by a scope issue. I simply used the **controller as** syntax, and declared every previous scope data with:

```
var self = this;
self.selectedIndex = 0;
self.displayMap = function (){
   self.selectedIndex = 1;
};
```

and my markup:

```
<div ng-controller="TrackingCtrl as tracking" layout-fill>
  <md-content ng-if="tracking.isSmart" layout-fill>
    <md-tabs md-selected="tracking.selectedIndex" layout-fill>
       <md-tab>.........</md-tab>
       <md-tab>.........</md-tab>
       <md-tab>.........</md-tab>
       <md-tab>
          <md-tab-label>{{ 'tracking.positions.TITLE' | translate }}</md-tab-label>
          <md-tab-body>
             <md-tab-content layout-fill flex>
                <button ng-click="tracking.displayMap();"></button>
             </md-tab-content>
          </md-tab-body>
       </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
 </md-content>
</div>
```

Works perfect now. I guess my ng-if was modifying my scope or so.

Comment: dude... thank you so much. I've been messing with this all morning. +1

Answer (score 10):

I'm glad you've found a workaround for your issue. To avoid that behaviour initially, you should probably have a look at this [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model).

Since your selectedIndex variable holds a primitive, every new Scope introduced - you already mentioned the ngIf - destroys the data binding and changes within the child scope will not have effect on the 'outside'.

In your case, just use...

```
$scope.vm = {
  selectedIndex: 0
};
```

...to follow **the dot rule**.

Comment: This just worked for me, should be the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I've misunderstood something about your question but this should work...

I've created a plunker and I cannot reproduce your behaviour, it's just working fine.

**View**:

```
<md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="selectedIndex">
  <md-tab id="tab1">
    <md-tab-label>Item One</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      data.selectedIndex = 0;
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>      
  <md-tab id="tab3">
    <md-tab-label>Item Two</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      data.selectedIndex = 1;
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>

<md-button ng-click="displayMap()">Map</md-button>
```

**Controller**:

```
  function AppCtrl ( $scope ) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;

    $scope.displayMap = function() {
      $scope.selectedIndex = 1; 
  };
```

Could you please check it? Hope it helps

[Plunker here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrMxWo)

Comment: It didn't work, but I've found a workaround. See my answer

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why you say it doesn't work...The plunker of my answer is working fine. Anyway, I'm glad you've solved the issue

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work when I put your code in my markup (because of my scope I think). Of course on Plunker it's ok

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

```
<div layout="column" flex>
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="vm.selectedIndex">
                <md-tab label="Genel" md-on-select="vm.selectedIndex = 0">
                  <div class="md-padding">{{vm.selectedIndex}}</div>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Sipariş / Planlama" md-on-select="vm.selectedIndex = 1">
                  <div class="md-padding">{{vm.selectedIndex}}</div>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Kalite Kontrol Oranları" md-on-select="vm.selectedIndex = 2">
                  <div class="md-padding">{{vm.selectedIndex}}</div>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="E-Posta" md-on-select="vm.selectedIndex = 3">
                  <div class="md-padding">{{vm.selectedIndex}}</div>
                </md-tab>
            </md-tabs>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With md-selected = 0 you go to the first tab. And md-selected = 1 to the second tab.

button:

```
<md-button ng-click="displayMap()">Map</md-button>
```

controller:

```
 $scope.displayMap = function() {
      $scope.selectedIndex = 1; //select second tab
  };
```

Comment: you test my suggest? I have angular material app 1.0.0 y it's working

Comment: It didn't work, but I've found a workaround. See my answer