# md-tabs: setting variable for md-selected not working when calling function from inside ui-router

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I have a `ui-router` template containing `md-tabs` from which some tabs are static, others are created dynamically using `ng-repeat` iterating through a given array of the data model.

Inside those dynamically created tabs there are three buttons to do the following

- move tab left by one position
- move tab right by one position

The `move tab` buttons call a function inside the same controller. The `$index` value of the currently shown tabs as well as the desired direction (`-1` for moving left, `1` for moving right) are passed to the function.

So the HTML-snippet for the view looks as follows:

```
<md-content flex layout-padding>
    <md-card>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-autoselect md-swipe-content md-selected="selectedTab">
            <md-tab id="{{ 'tab' + $index }}" data-ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by $index">
                <md-tab-label>Tab {{ $index + 1 }}</md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <div flex layout="row">
                                <div flex><span class="md-headline">Tab {{ $index + 1 }}</span></div>
                                <div flex align="right">
                                    <md-button ng-click="moveTab(-1, $index)">Move tab left</md-button>
                                    <md-button ng-click="moveTab(1, $index)">Move tab right</md-button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>
                    <md-card-content>
                    <p>This is tab {{ $index + 1 }}</p>
                    </md-card-content>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
```

The function moving the tabs is implemented in `MainController` as:

```
$scope.moveTab = function(direction, TabIdx) {
    var staticTabs = 3

    var arr = $scope.tabs
    var fromIdx = sectorIdx
    var toIdx = tabIdx + direction

    // correct `toIdx` in order to prevent index overflow for first/last array element
    if (toIdx < 0) {
        toIdx = arr.length - 1
    } else if (toIdx > arr.length-1) {
        toIdx = 0
    }
    else {
        ; // nothing to do here since `toIdx` does not need to be corrected
    }

    var tab = arr.splice(fromIdx, 1)[0]
    arr.splice(toIdx, 0, tab)

    $scope.selectedTab = staticTabs + toIdx
    console.log($scope.selectedTab)
}
```

After clicking the desired button to move a tab, the data of the according tab neigbour is displayed as desired.
This shows that maniupulating the `$scope.tabs` array works correctly. Additionally the log-message shows that even the new value for `$scope.selectedTab` is calculated correctly.
However, the new tab is not selected in the view.

This confuses me hence both variables `$scope.tabs` and `$scope.selectedTab` are defined in the same controller and should be part of the same `$scope` instance.
In addition, the manipulated `$scope.tabs` array is used in other views and shows the tab data in the new order, whereas the new value for `$scope.selectedTab` does not seem to be available and the shown tab does not change.

Comment: If you got here through a search like I did, more info in the (related by perhaps not duplicate) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936155/change-index-of-angular-md-tabs-have-no-effect-at-all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a problem of scope inheritance since data-bindings using other datatypes than objects do not have two-way-binding when inheriting the parent scope.

See the docs:

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It
>   doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens
>   is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the
>   parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is
>   doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New
>   AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch,
>   ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem
>   often shows up when these directives are involved. [...]
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models [...]

After changing

```
selectedTab
```

to

```
selectedTab.inputTab
```

in both the given HTML- and JS-snippets everything works as expected.