# why scope is not updating once changed by directive in ionic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a simple directive which shows notification, user can tap on it to close it. its not working as expected (once hide by user its not showing again) in ionic, and same thing it working on angular only.

[Angular Demo](http://jsbin.com/pulipazimo/edit?html,js,output)

[Ionic CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPEmVB?editors=1000)

Here is directive code

```
angular.module('app').directive('notificationBar', [function(){
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : {
      msg : '@',
      type : '@',
      show : '='
    },
    template : '<div ng-click="hideIt()" ng-show="show" class="alert {{type}}"><span>&times;</span> {{ msg }}</div>',
    link : function ( scope, elem, attr ) {
      scope.type = attr.type || 'alert-danger';

      scope.hideIt = function () {
          scope.show = false;
      };

      // for debugging 
      scope.$watch('show', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.info('old show val', oldValue);
        console.info('new show val', newValue);
      });

     }
   };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like *dot rule* in angular js is to blame here. Because `error` is a primitive value, once that's changed in the controller scope, the variable that directive is watching for is referring to *old* value.

Why is this different between web and ionic, not sure. But to solve this, warp `error` inside an object and user `dot notation` to access it.

Like so:

```
$scope.error = {
   error: true
};

<div notification-bar show="error.error" msg="Something is wrong here :( " type="alert-danger"></div>
```

Here's the updated code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjrRRJ?editors=1011

For more information on this `dot rule` I mentioned, here's a good stackoverflow post which is worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/841804 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/841804