# How to bind value from controller for ionic radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, radio-button

Im trying to bind value of radio button from ionic controller. The following is the code i have used for.

```
 <div class="list">
            <ion-radio ng-model="SearchChoice" ng-value="All" ng-click="SearchByFilter('All')"> ALL <div id="badge-all" class="count-jkt"> <span ng-bind="AllCount.OnGoing"></span></div></ion-radio>
            <ion-radio ng-model="SearchChoice" ng-value="New" ng-click="SearchByFilter('New')"> NEW <div id="badge-new" class="count-jkt">{{AllCount.New}}</div></ion-radio>
        </div>
```

and my controller is,

```
       .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

         $scope.SearchChoice = "All";
        $scope.SearchByFilter = function(item) {
          console.log( "Filter:", item);
        };
      });
```

Here the value is not binding properly. Kindly help me guys!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it using the `.` notation ?

```
<div class="list">
    <ion-radio ng-model="model.SearchChoice" ng-value="All" ng-click="SearchByFilter('All')"> ALL <div id="badge-all" class="count-jkt"> <span ng-bind="AllCount.OnGoing"></span></div></ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="model.SearchChoice" ng-value="New" ng-click="SearchByFilter('New')"> NEW <div id="badge-new" class="count-jkt">{{AllCount.New}}</div></ion-radio>
</div>

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        SearchChoice: "All"
    };

    $scope.SearchByFilter = function(item) {
        console.log( "Filter:", item);
    };
});
```

For more info about the `.` notation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model).

Comment: Im getting the default value. but, its not shows as selected. when i remove ng-model it shows selected. But i can get value in model.SearchChoice. I dont know what i have missed!

Comment: Could you try `value=` instead of `ng-value=` ?