# Textarea won't clear after clearing attached model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `textarea` attached to a `$scope` variable called `newNoteText`. The html is:

```
<textarea spellcheck="true"               
          ng-model="newNoteText"></textarea>
```

There's also a button that saves the typed note.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
       ng-click="btnPost_clicked(newNoteText)">Post
</button>
```

Here's the controller function `btnPost_clicked`:

```
        $scope.btnPost_clicked = function(newNoteText) {
            $scope.addNote(newNoteText);
            $scope.newNoteText = '';
        }
```

I confirmed via console.log that $scope.newNoteText is being reset to an empty string. But the textarea still holds the old text.

Comment: I don't think that should be problem... does `text-area` is inside `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @PankajParkar No, it's not in an `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @Legion It might be helpful if you post some more code

Comment: @Legion could you reproduce problem in plunkr?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in some demo fiddle or plunkr? for me it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5darc76z/   looks like some typo

Comment: This could be a result of breaking the rule of always using an object in `ng-model`. If there are child scopes involved you lose binding of primitives

Comment: @MaximShoustin Tried that. It works there. Just not in app.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/1175966. Watch the 3  minute video too

Comment: @charlietfl You are correct. All I wanted was a placeholder variable. I really dislike this aspect of angular. If a particular field doesn't match up with my viewmodel I have to create a dummy object and dummy property. In these cases it seems so much cleaner, easier and performant to just use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Not difficult if you always use objects in scope. One object can cover a lot of variables...or using `controllerAs` avoids needing to create object and makes problem go away

Comment: @charlietfl I do use models on $scope. But in cases like this where a field is being used to create a new object (a new note in this case) there is no existing object to attach it to. Basically, any time a field is acting as a user driven object generator I find model binding becomes clumsy. I know it can be done, but I can't think of a circumstance where it should be done.

Comment: You say that but you are using primitive for `$scope.newNoteText`. If you had `$scope.model={}` and set `$scope.model.newNoteText='some value'` and `ng-model="model.newNoteText"` would work fine

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, except newNoteText shouldn't be part of my model. I attach my model to the $scope, but my model doesn't have properties that are UI specific. I see this as corrupting my domain models with UI details.

Comment: huh? not UI specific at all. You want to work with that model data for `newNoteText` in controller so what does UI matter?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen only when you get an error in $scope.addNote(newNoteText). See below code and try jsfiddle I created. I am just logging newNoteText in addNote and everything seem to be working fine.

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <textarea spellcheck="true"               
          ng-model="newNoteText"></textarea>

  <div>{{txt}}</div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
       ng-click="btnPost_clicked(newNoteText)">Post
</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.txt = '';

  $scope.btnPost_clicked = function(newNoteText) {
    $scope.addNote(newNoteText);
    $scope.newNoteText = '';
  };

  $scope.addNote = function(newNoteText) {
    console.log(newNoteText);
  }
}]);
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/d89ftrmg/

Comment: Not the only reason it can happen...child scope nesting such as in `ng-if` or `ng-include` will break bindings of primitives also

Comment: Yes, but don't you think in that case even we should not be able to call $scope.btnPost_clicked ?

Comment: No...because functions aren't primitives so there is inheritance in child scopes