# Angular directive scope. How to isolate single variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make input wrapper with angular directives and it should have different labels. Now I even can't access model outside the input (even with scope: false).

HTML:

```
<input-block data-label="my label">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" name="test" ng-model="test"/>
</input-block>

Test: {{test}} <!--not working-->
```

Angular:

```
profileApp.directive('inputBlock', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '' +
        '<div class="input-block">' +
            '<span class="input-text">{{label}}</span>' +
            '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.label;
        }
    };
});
```

The only idea for now is to find a way to isolate single variable or something similar

Comment: *always always always* use an object in ng-model !

Comment: @charlietfl that doesn't sound right. What do you do for `<input type="text">`?

Comment: not sure what you mean @Phil

Comment: @charlietfl well, unless you're including strings as objects (which I suppose technically they are), wouldn't you normally use a string with `<input type="text" ng-model="someStringVariable">`?

Comment: @Phil am talking about the golden [dot in ng-model rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/why-dont-the-angularjs-docs-use-a-dot-in-the-model-directive)

Comment: Ah, right. I thought you meant in relation to the actual property in `ng-model`. Scope inheritance does indeed make a mess of things :)

Comment: @Phil strings are primitives in Javascript, not objects (as they are in many other languages). This can cause some unexpected behavior if one is not aware.

Comment: @NateVaughan fair point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as was already said here, just use object for your *ng-model*:

```
<body ng-init="model = {}">
  <input-block data-label="my label2">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" name="test" ng-model="model.test"/>
  </input-block>

  Test: {{model.test}}
</body>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XxeMlVv6I6qOwjPoCUtQ?p=preview

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And what about `label`? http://plnkr.co/edit/ncr6QtZ4Diy2uTHYA7dF?p=preview

Comment: Just added scope: true and it works. Thanks for help.