# Angular js inside of an ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, datatables

I know this is not how the code should be structured but I am limited.  I am trying to include a datatable inside angular ng-if section.  When I take off the ng-if statement the js runs fine.  I am looking for ways around this where it works.  I have tried to move the js outside of the ng-if, but then the datatable doesn't work.  Any hint in the right direction would be helpful.  Thanks.

```
<div ng-if="test">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Results table -->
    <table id="example2" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Created On</th>
                <th>Table ID</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-click="displayStatementToggle()">
                <th>123</th>
                <th>2011-04-28 13:32:07</th>
                <th>Mortgage</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-click="displayStatementToggle()">
                <th>123</th>
                <th>2016-04-18 14:36:07</th>
                <th>Monthly</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example2').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-if will create a child scope which is different from your controller scope. Try to use ng-show instead

```
<div ng-show="test">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Results table -->
    <table id="example2" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Created On</th>
                <th>Table ID</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-click="displayStatementToggle()">
                <th>123</th>
                <th>2011-04-28 13:32:07</th>
                <th>Mortgage</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-click="displayStatementToggle()">
                <th>123</th>
                <th>2016-04-18 14:36:07</th>
                <th>Monthly</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example2').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` has its own scope, so the functions you are calling are undefined inside of it.

`ng-show` is a possible solution, but **[has it's own caveats](http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/)**.

Plase, take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/3701009)**, which explains the importance of using the **dot** in your directives. Even if you choose to use `ng-show`, I would recommend that you refactor your controller and view to avoid further complications down the road.

If you are new to angular, don't hesitate to read [John Papa's styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), which covers that situation and many others.