# How do you propagate scope values from directives to the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a complex data structure that requires lots of inline editing. To make the code easier, much of the breaking down of components over this data structure has been placed into nested directives.

For example, here is an example of the data structure:

```
{
   "pageElements":[
      {
         "id":1721,
         "pageId":861,
         "position":0,
         "type":"Paragraph",
         "text":"<p>Who is the captain of the Enterprise NX-01?</p>"
      },
      {
         "id":1722,
         "pageId":861,
         "position":1,
         "type":"Question",
         "question":{
            "id":1664,
            "type":"ShortAnswer",
            "successMessage":"You really know your captains!",
            "hints":[

            ],
            "answerAllowance":"SINGLE",
            "minimumNumberOfKeywords":1,
            "keywords":[
               {
                  "id":45394,
                  "text":"John Archer",
                  "accuracy":0,
                  "ignoreCase":false
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2786,
         "pageId":861,
         "position":2,
         "type":"Paragraph",
         "text":"<p>fafadffadfda</p>"
      }
   ]
}
```

Imagine the main page for this controller iterates over `pageElements`:

```
<ol class="pageElements">
    <li ng-repeat="pageElement in page.pageElements">
        <!-- page-element directive uses $compile 
             to create a specific DOM based on pageElement.type -->
        <div page-element ng-model="pageElement"></div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Now, let's imagine that some modifications of a single `pageElement` occur within the `page-element` directive (or some child directive). How do we get those modifications into the `page.pageElements` list? For some reason, I can get changes to propagate to parent directives if they are just objects, but once the parent object is contained within a list, the updates no longer propagate.

How can I solve this? Is the problem really with `ng-repeat` stopping the propagation upwards?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand the question. As an example are you trying to change something like the "minimumNumbeOfKeywords" field or add a keyword object to your keywords list? It sounds like you have a scope hierarchy issue, but difficult to pinpoint without a more complete example.

Comment: @RyanQ It's all good, I solve with the dot notation problem. Apparantly I am not the first person to come across this with ng-repeat. It looks like a scope issue, but my posted answer links the stackoverflow thread that goes into more detail about the actual problem. I am confident this solved the issue.

Comment: Yeahp the scope hierarchy (aka dot notation) problem gets quite a few people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it this way. Apparantly models need to have a containing object reference while inside of ngRepeat:

```
<ol class="pageElements">
    <li ng-repeat="pageElement in page.pageElements">
        <div page-element model="page.pageElements[$index]"></div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

So, the trick was `page.pageElements[$index]` instead of `pageElement`

I got this solution from:

[Directive isolate scope with ng-repeat scope in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623698/directive-isolate-scope-with-ng-repeat-scope)

Comment: I discovered a the exact same solution last night, but given the elegance that Angular gives, it felt like the wrong solution, to be passing around array elements, etc. This morning I continued work and found that the cause of the problem was not Angular, but the way in which I was copying the model object inside the directive (for editing), and then over-writing the original scope object (having $$hashKey) with the editied model object. The solution was to copy the changed properties back into the scope object instead of overwriting it completely.

Answer (score 1):

to share data between directive and controllers use SERVICE, it is nothing but the injections that you do in controllers for eg: $http,$rootScope,$scope
similarly you can have user defined services.. inject it in your controller and directive and use to exchange data!

Second part: how to tell a controller that a value has changed in directive? say your directive has a variable A and on change of A you want to do something in controller then you have following two ways

1. Either use $watch
2. or use $emit method (preferably use this! it is a kind of broadcast i.e. when the change occurs on A then this $emit is fired and all controllers will have access to this $emit event
   you can listen to it and do what ever you want to trigger)

Comment: Watches are being used. There are about half a dozen nestings of directives that all uses watches. When the leaf directive changes something, it does propagate to the parents. The only issue was that it stopped at `ngRepeat`, and didn't propagate to `page.pageElements`, as I said in my question. A service can't be used because managing the nested hierarchy of the object graph would be a total nightmare.

Comment: so if the propagation is not happening beyond ng-repeat then use $emit to fire a broadcast and this will be accessible to all the controllers. oki i just read your answer seems nice

Comment: It was being was propagated in a sense, but it was not a reference to the object - it was just a primitive value because it was not using a dot notation. So while the inner childs - even ngRepeat - were getting updated, page.pageElements was still stuck with the old values.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the directive scope propperly. Take a look at this code

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="app">
            <div ng-controller="ctrl">
                <div>
                    <h1>I am the parent scope.</h1>
                    {{page}}
                </div>
                <ol class="pageElements">
                    <li ng-repeat="pageElement in page.pageElements">
                        <!-- page-element directive uses $compile 
                             to create elemented based on type -->
                        <div>
                            <h2>I am still the parent scope, only that I watch one element</h2>
                            {{pageElement}}
                        </div>>
                        <div page-element my-page-element="pageElement"></div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('app', [])
                .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
                    $scope.page = {"pageElements":[{"id":1721,"pageId":861,"position":0,"type":"Paragraph","text":"<p>Who is the captain of the Enterprise NX-01?</p>"},{"id":1722,"pageId":861,"position":1,"type":"Question","question":{"id":1664,"type":"ShortAnswer","successMessage":"You really know your captains!","hints":[],"answerAllowance":"SINGLE","minimumNumberOfKeywords":1,"keywords":[{"id":45394,"text":"John Archer","accuracy":0,"ignoreCase":false}]}},{"id":2786,"pageId":861,"position":2,"type":"Paragraph","text":"<p>fafadffadfda</p>"}]};
                })
                .directive('pageElement', function() {
                    return {
                        template: '<div><h3>I am the directive scope. You can change the "text" property here to see it propagate.</h3><input ng-model="pageElement.text"><p>{{pageElement.text}}</p><div>{{pageElement}}<div></div>',
                        scope: {
                            pageElement: '=myPageElement'
                        }
                    };
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9rcu3/

The magic is in the directive scope binding:

```
scope: {
    pageElement: '=myPageElement'
}
```

Take a look at the angular developer guide, they have an awesome tutorial on building directives:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Yes, I can get the values viewable like yours no problem... the code I am working with is actually non-trivial. I am simplifying it greatly. I did actually figure it out. By using the dot notation, we can get angular to do 2-way binding correctly. Now when a `pageElement` is updated in the child directives, it will actually propagate correct to `page.pageElements`. Without the dot notation, it won't - the scope will be isolated within `ngRepeat`.