# Angularjs: $scope.variable not in sync with view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I feel pretty stupid about this question because I can't reproduce this problem in plunker, but it does happen in my real project.

I created this plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fhn42XKYtEzGexistyt?p=preview), I'm trying to watch the scope variable searchString, it works fine in this plunker, but not in my real project. $scope.searchString stays empty. However, html is working fine. What could be possible cause?

I'm using angular with breeze, as I tried it out, if I attach searchString to an entity object, then, it works. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a primitive (string, boolean, number, etc), you can't reference it. When you use an object or array, you can reference and modify it's members.

That means, when you you do a

```js
$scope.$watch('searchString', function(str, oldValue) {
  console.log(str.length);
});
```

You are checking for the new length of `searchString`, that MIGHT be null/undefined/empty when `$watch` is first called and `oldValue` will contain the current value. so if you are modifying `searchString` from another scope or directive, it won't be affected, because the new scopes `searchString` is the one being changed (that is, the current instance value). For it to effectively be changed where it was defined, you should use:

```js
$scope.search = {input: ''};

$scope.$watch('search.input', function(str, oldValue) {
  console.log(str.length);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EFdnhQE1nN5vsBJR1sEm?p=preview

And a brief explanation on `$watch`: `scope.$watch` will be called when the `$digest` cycle has completed. if you change your data (primitives or even objects) from outside a non-angular event (like `element.on('click' ...)` on jQuery), you must call `$scope.$apply()` or `$timeout` to reflect it on your UI. otherwise, from an `ng-click`, or changes to a model from an input, your `$digest` is called automatically, thus updating everything in real time. Some info about $scope and inheritance here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15645354/647380

Comment: Thanks for explanation. However, why it is working in the plunker I created?

Comment: well, without your real code, it's hard to tell. if the code in the plnkr is exactly the same, then maybe it could be an angular version mismatch, since the plnkr is using the last angular stable.